# CKEditor restore element / undo all changes

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Is there a way to restore the original content / undo all changes of an element that had become an Inline-CKEditor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

After instantiating CKEditor I save the initial content with `CKEDITOR.editor1.getData()` to a custom variable `CKEDITOR.editor1.firstSnapshot`. Later when I want to restore it I write it back with `CKEDITOR.editor1.setData(CKEDITOR.editor1.firstSnapshot);`

At first I wanted to use `getSnapshot()` but however it always returned `true`, so that didn't work for me.

Comment: Using ``getSnapshot()`` and ``loadSnapshot()`` is working fine on my Ckeditor 4.2, otherwise I am doing it the same way (saving the snapshot and bringing it back in if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to exist a build-in function for that, see for example [this ticket](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/5346).

Some propose workarounds like a button with `onclick` javascript event, which reloads a page. Or saving the initial data inside of the editor and use javascript to replace the content with that on an event again. ([Here is a thread concerning your request with the mentioned tricks.](http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/Resetting-textarea-PHP-content))

Answer (score 0):

I want to share a different approach to problem. I'm using inline CKEditor, and have on blur event (when user unfocus ckeditor) which prompt option for saving content or rollback changes.

For case of rollback - i just put checkDirty() - function which check if instance has changes - in while loop, so undo executes in each true until ckeditor will be restored to initial state.

Code will look like this:

```
CKEDITOR.instances["editor"].on('blur', function (evt) {
    if (confirm("Do you wish to roll back changes ?")) {
        while (CKEDITOR.instances["editor"].checkDirty())   {
            CKEDITOR.instances["editor"].execCommand('undo');
        }
    } else {
        // do nothing!
    }                        
})
```